# module base64.decode yields corrupt pdf base64 encoded file

Tags: python, base64

Hello when i try to decode image like this

"example_label.b64" file is here (http://ge.tt/27odGly/v/0)

i see corrupted pdf, looks like base64 decoding corrupt this file.

Can you help me?

Here code example.

```
import base64
with open('example_label.b64','r+') as f:
    data = f.read()
    f.close()
# data = data.decode('base64')
#or
data = base64.b64decode(data)
with open('example_label.pdf','w+') as f:
    f.write(data)
    f.close()
```

Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide the md5 checksum of the original pdf file?

Comment: The decoded pdf seems right in  my machine

Comment: here bd9a4e16d45fe01bfc77a2af6afe1b8b md5 of original file

Comment: You use Linux?
I use Windows 8, and Python 2.7.3 x32. Maybe this is problem?

Comment: Yes, Windows text mode files in Python **is** the problem; see my answer.

Comment: @Darius I decode the base64 string with your code and got a pdf has the same md5. The pdf seems OK, why do you think it is corrupted?

Comment: As a site note, why are you using `r+` mode (which means "read and write") for an input file you only plan to read? And why are you calling `close` when you're already using `with`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your write mode should specify binary or else you risk newline conversion depending on your platform. That is

```
open('example_label.pdf', 'wb')
```

The file decodes just fine on my system yielding checksums of

```
$ md5sum example_label.pdf 
bd9a4e16d45fe01bfc77a2af6afe1b8b  example_label.pdf
$ sha1sum example_label.pdf 
a9b77217793ef05f212b0619248480411f6ed4a1  example_label.pdf
```

and is a US postal service label with dummy addresses in it.

Comment: Newline conversion is so handy, but they *never* should have made it the default.